# Copy local file to vpn finder

Tags: macos, vpn

I am connected to a remote server with VPN. I want to copy and paste one file to that server. When I am trying to drag and drop, it doesnt let me do that. I am new to this and this is really frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you've got permission to write to the remote share.

Comment: Do you control the remote server? Is it a AFP or SMB share? What's the operating system? if you don't control it get the administrator to check your users permissions.

Comment: No. I dont have the control. I have to check with admin. Thanks again for answer.